# How to override the entrypoint like __libc_start_main with g++

Tags: gcc, g++

We want to inject some functions before user's main function and found `LD_PRELOAD` to override `__libc_start_main` would work for C programes with `gcc`.

However, it doesn't work with cpp file which may use g++ by default. We have dumped the symbol and found the difference between binaries from gcc and g++. After compiling with `g++`, the libc start main function was rename and we don't know how to override it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to use `__attribute__((constructor))` instead of overwriting `__libc_start_main` to add logic before main function.

This could be the different of implementation between `g++` and `gcc` and we may not overwrite it with the current implementation of `g++`. Please comment and notify me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is the *name mangling* scheme used by C++.

To bypass mangling, use `extern "C"` on the function's definition or an `extern "C"` block:

```
void no_extern_c(int, int) {}

extern "C"
void with_extern_c(int, int) {}

$ nm -D demo.so  
...
00000000000005b7 T with_extern_c
00000000000005aa T _Z11no_extern_cii
```

Usually you use this to declare functions that are part of a C API, but the same reason is why it's needed there (or part of it at least), which is that the mangled name is what you'd have to use from C code as well.